# react native firebase realtime data base not display show photo

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I use firebase realtime database, I can pull data of photo
But will use photo in realtime database, It's not display a component flatlist.

my code get database:

```
componentDidMount() {
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user != null) {
    const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
    const userRef = rootRef.child(`user/${user.uid}/car`);
    this.setState({ uid: user.uid })
    userRef.on('value', (childSnapshot) => {
      const cars = [];
      childSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        cars.push({
          distance: doc.val().distance,
          time: doc.val().time,
          price: doc.val().price,
          photo:doc.val().photo,
          key: doc.key,
        });
        this.setState({
          cars: Object.values(cars)
        })
      });
    })
  }
});
```

}

Flatist

```
<FlatList data={this.state.cars}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <List>
              <ListItem avatar>
                  <Image style={{width:50,height:50}} source={item.photo}></Image>
              </ListItem>
            </List>)}
        />
```

Not a show photo ["Picture"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGdFe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you store to the photo is a local file URL on the device where you add it. This will only work on the device where the photo already exists, and even then it may stop working at any time.

What you'll want to do is upload the photo to a server, where all users can see it. For example, you could [upload the photo with the Firebase Storage SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files), then request a download URL (see the end of [this example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#full_example)), and write *that* URL to the database. With such a download URL all users can read the picture.

Comment: Okay,i will try.
Thank you.